# Issue updating Heroku JDK to 1.7 with Play 2.2.3

Tags: java, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.2

I am trying to update Heroku to run with JDK 1.7, from a Windows development environment.

In following with the docs [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/add-java-version-to-an-existing-maven-app) I created a system.properties file in my app's root directory, containing the following: java.runtime.version=1.7

I then manually went into Heroku's config variables and added this: /app/.jdk/bin
to the beginning of the path.

I committed my change and pushed it to the server. However, the Heroku push logs only say "Installing OpenJDK", and don't mention which version is being installed. My code then results in a Major.Minor 51.0 compile error resulting in compilation with the Heroku standard OpenJDK1.6

For some reason Heroku is not updating the JDK! Any help would be much appreciated.